# how do I retrieve audio and video file uploaded to parse.com using the javascript api

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, html5-video, ionic-framework

using parse.com's JavaScript SDK, I have successfully uploaded two media items and gotten the upload url back from the Parse.File object:

For example:

audio: http://files.parsetfss.com/9fbcaa0f-8cb6-4d8d-8001-a046d33cf96e/tfss-76d86338-4e56-40d4-b6d0-7d45d53ea839-audio_001.wav

video: http://files.parsetfss.com/9fbcaa0f-8cb6-4d8d-8001-a046d33cf96e/tfss-109d25e9-aa92-44d1-9d9c-100711f136e1-capturedvideo.MOV

however when I try to retrieve those files by setting the src="", I get:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 416
>   (Requested Range Not Satisfiable)

any ideas why this would be?

The documentation suggests using

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: profilePhoto.url() }).then(function(response) {
  // The file contents are in response.buffer.
});
```

but "httpRequest" is undefined in the 'Parse' object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

little late, but hope I can still help. Use this:

```
var audioFile = myParseObject.get('ColumnNameWithAudioFile');
var audio = new Audio(audioFile.url());
audio.play();
```

Works for me!